# Programmatically add refinement filter to a Search refiner

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-search, refiner

I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.eliostruyf.com/part-5-search-refiner-control-methods-explained/

Everytime I run this, it alters the ribbon bar so that I can't "Stop Editing" the page that I've added my script editor webpart to.

```
<script>
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("runAfterEverythingElse")
function runAfterEverythingElse(){
    var refiner = $getClientControl(document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl40_g_f26d831b_bc2d_4961_928b_b3969eba84d7_csr1"));
refiner.addRefinementFilter('FileType', 'html');
}
</script>
```

Comment: The ribbon gets altered when there is error in the code which loads on page loading.

Comment: which web part are you using? and why are you adding refinement filter using javascript instead of adding refinement filter in OOTB way?

Comment: I have a page that presents 9 icons.. Pretend these are product categories.. books, music, etc.  The user picks a category and is brought to the search results page that is filtered on that category.  The issue is if the user then executes a keyword search the filter is removed and a new search is issued.  If you select a category on Amazon like books and then enter a keyword search, everything is still filtered by books and the keyword you just issued.